# Lottie animation error after change color of animation

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, lottie

Exception : Caused by: com.airbnb.lottie.parser.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected a double but was END_ARRAY at path $.layers[3].shapes[0].it[1].c.k[3]

Describe the bug : normal animation is working but after change color of animation at https://editor.lottiefiles.com/
it crash

version of Lottie : 3.4.1

```
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.1"
```

version of Android : Android 12

I thought it problem with animation I selected so I try to another animation but still it crash after I change color of animation.
loot like Lottie have bug on there editor(https://editor.lottiefiles.com/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can bump lootie library to:

```
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.5.0"
```

I made tests with your lootie file and it`s working.

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/test" />
```

[image: Your lootie]

Comment: thank it's work but I also found the solution via using classic editor to change animation color and it's working

Comment: I updated Lottie from 3.4.0 to 3.5.0 as shown here and it worked.